# rank function always brings back contiguous ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a simple table that has ids in them.

```
1
5
22
```

When I do the following

```
select *, rank() over (order by id) as rank from my table
```

the rank comes back as

```
1
2
3
```

I don't understand why the ranking is contiguous? I was expecting something like

```
1
4
17
```

I would have expected the contiguous behavior from the `dense_rank` function.

Comment: If you use `RANK()` on the data `{1.5, 1.5, 2.9}` you'll get `1,1,3` - The first two items are tied at ***first***, but the third item is still ***third***. `DENSE_RANK()`, however, doesn't allow gaps, so that would have returned `1,1,2` *(first, first, second)*. What is not clear is why you'd expect ranks `1,4,17` from 3 items? There are only three items, so the ranks must be `1st` or `2nd` or `3rd`. *(If there are three runners in a race, none of them rank 17th, no matter how slow they are...)* Are you trying to rank your data, or work out the size of the gaps between your items?

Comment: The results I am seeing seems to be what row_numer() would bring back not rank(). I was expecting 1,4,17 because I thought the rank was based on the difference, (4-1) = 3 is the rank which has more of a weigh. I'm confused on what the difference between rank() and row_numer() is then?

Comment: Then check my example again. `ROW_NUMBER()` always returns `1,2,3,etc`, even if two items have exactly the same value. `RANK()`, however, recognises that two items are tied and so you can get the results `1,1,3` *(first, first, third)* - Just like two competitors being tied for first place in a competition *(They're both ranked first, but the next competitior is ranked third)*. `DENSE_RANK()` can't return `1, 1, 3`, instead all the gaps are filled in and you get `1, 1, 2` *(first, first, second)*. Look at the answers here, read the manual, and most of all, test it with your own data..

Answer (score 2):

All ID's are different, that is the reason for that behaviour. Ranking functions come into play when the values you order by are equal.

```
create table TableName(id int);
insert into TableName values(1);
insert into TableName values(5);
insert into TableName values(5);
insert into TableName values(22);
insert into TableName values(22);
insert into TableName values(22);

select *, 
rank() over (order by id) as rank,
dense_rank() over (order by id) as dense_rank,
row_number() over (order by id) as row_num
from TableName

ID  RANK    DENSE_RANK  ROW_NUM
1   1         1         1
5   2         2         2
5   2         2         3
22  4         3         4
22  4         3         5
22  4         3         6
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0abe/1/0)

[Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are the id's contiguous?  If there are no ties, then RANK and DENSE_RANK will return the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT *, 
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY id) as rank
  FROM tablename
 )
SELECT 
  c1.Id,
  (c1.id - ISNULL(c2.ID, 0)) rank
FROM CTE c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.rank - c2.rank = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b7e4/9)